# img:hover not working in ie

Tags: html, css

css:

```
.myim { 
    width:50; 
    height:50;
}
.mydiv { 
    float:right; 
    position:absolute; 
    -index:2;
}
.myim:hover {
    width:50;
    height:50;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    filter:alpha(opacity=95) !important;
    opacity: 0.98 !important; 
    -moz-opacity:11;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
  <a href="#"><img class='myim'></a>
</div>
```

I want that whenever the mouseover is done on the image it should have little bit of transparency.

All above coding works well in FF, but it's not working in IE at all.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I remember, IE doesn't identify hover for non-a tags.

Comment: Put the hover in the A tag you have.

Answer (score 0):

hover can be applied only to anchot tags....

the better solution for your query is to use jquery. its very simple to learn and build good website.

for jquery video tutorials see this link http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/. if you are a newbee to jquery this video tutorial will be so useful..

Comment: yep , I got it. And it's working now as expected.

Thanks all