# Image map with different overlays/tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am relatively new to coding in general and I thought I could ask here for some help.

I have created an image map for a picture. 
Different sections should show a different overlay or speechbubble tooltip with a fixed position next to the hovered area (with text) and clickable links. But I have no idea on how to do this properly.

Basically, an interactive instruction.

My first tries were somewhat promising (for me) in an editor, but failed in the "field test" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="PICTURE LINK" 
width="850" height="600" alt="MitarbeiterAnsicht" usemap="#map1">

<map name="map1">

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="20, 195, 150, 220" alt="Schulungssuche" >
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Schulungssuche</b><br>Hier können sie nach 
Titel,<br>LMS Code oder Schlagwörtern suchen </span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="13, 310, 187, 500" alt="Colleges" >
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Colleges</b><br>Colleges sind bestimmte 
Lehrangebote für <br>veschiedene Funktionen und <br>Bereiche</span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="190, 158, 557, 550" alt="Schulungsplan" 
href="LINK">
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Schulungsplan</b><br>Der Schulungsplan 
beinhaltet alle Schulungen,<br>zu denen Sie bereits angemeldet sind, die 
Sie<br>sich selbst zugewiesen haben, die Ihr Vorgesetzter<br>ihnen 
zugewiesen hat oder Compliance Schulungen.<br><font 
color="#FF0000">Compliance Schulungen müssen bearbeitet werden !<br>Sie 
haben ein Fälligkeitsdatum. Überschreiten Sie<br>dieses Fälligkeitsdatum, so 
wird automatisch ihr<br>Vorgesetzer informiert!</font><br><font 
color="0000ff">-> Fragen zu Compliance Schulungen? Box anklicken</font>
</span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="565, 158, 740, 347" alt="Absolviert" >
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Absolvierte Schulungen</b><br>Die Lernhistorie 
zeigt alle, in den letzten 30<br>Tagen absolvierten Schulungen an.</span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="565, 453, 647, 470" alt="FAQ"> <b>Häufig 
gestellte Fragen</b><br><font 
color="0000ff"> Box anklicken, um zum FAQ weitergeleitet zu werden</font>
</span> 
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="565, 485, 647, 505" alt="Optionen" href="LINK" >
<span class="tooltiptext"> <b>Optionen</b><br>Beschreibung<font 
color="0000ff">Link</font></span>
 </div>

</map>

<style>
.tooltip {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
cursor: help;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
visibility: hidden;
width: 200px;
background-color: grey;
color: #fff;
text-align: left;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px 5px;
border: 1px dotted black;

position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
visibility: visible;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if this looks really messy.

Thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: tip: put your styles inside the `<head>` tag

Comment: well using map is quite an old paradigm.
Can you explain a little more about what you're trying to get here? is it only displaying a tooltip while hovering over an image?

Comment: @Pascal T: Tooltip will not remain there when you hover-out from that coordinate. Then how you will click the links. Please see the answer posted by me. I think that meets all your requirement.

Comment: @Roysh I have an image with different areas. Each area should have a tooltip (right above the area) that shows up if you hover over it. Additionally maybe timed, so that I could put links in (otherwise I'll link the area directly)

Comment: Do you have the link to the exact image?

Comment: Not necessary, I mostly used the code below. The only problem I have now is that `:hover` is not working in IE11 (works fine in chrome)

Comment: If you can give me a link to the image and tell me exactly what parts should display a tooltip, I can fix it right away. If all the areas you have there are rectangles, there's a much simple way

Comment: @PascalT - I've just posted an answer. Let me know if that's what you need

Comment: @Roysh Thanks, I'll look into it on monday when I'm in my office again if that's okay  :) I am most likely not allowed to post the picture, since it is not owned by me (company).

Comment: Sure. 
let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here's my approach:

I would avoid using img and map tags.
If the areas you need on the image are only rectangles, I do believe it's the best approach.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a container div and set its background to your image. You can also set the height and the width according to your image size. Set this div to be **position relative or absolute**.
2. Create children divs according to the hover areas you want to have. Set these div with **position absolute** and give them width and height according to the area you want to hover on.
3. Inside each children div create another div in which you'll enter the tooltip text. Set this div to be `display: none`
4. Add css for hover state so that the tooltip div will be set to `display:block`

Your HTML should look like

```
<div class="main-img">
  <div class="invisible-area area-one">
    <div class="tooltip">
     I'm a tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="invisible-area area-two">
    <div class="tooltip">
     I'm another tooltip!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.main-img {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('your image URL here') no-repeat center;
  
}
.invisible-area {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.area-one{
    top: 135px; //set here the position of the area
    left: 90px;
}
.area-two {
  top: 135px; //other area position
  left: 275px; 
}
.tooltip {
  display: none;
 /*optional tooltip design*/
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.invisible-area:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ky63ead/5/) - hover over the head of the characters in the image

**EDIT**

Here's another [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ky63ead/13/) which includes the image you've uploaded.
You should add more invisible-area divs along with their tooltip.
All you need to do is to give them the exact width and height and position (top, left).

Comment: So, I uploaded just the overlay to imgur : [Overlay](http://imgur.com/J3QYOZO), I used the map before because it seemed simpler :) Is it possible to have different area and tooltip sizes (one box hasnot that much content, the other tons e.g) ? It will be 600 x 850 (height x width)

Comment: Yes.
Check my fiddle- you can set the height and width of every 'invisible-area'. You can do the same with the tooltips

Comment: Okay, yeah I checked it. So `.invisible-area .area-one {` and customize the height and width ? It sets the area and the tooltip size at the same time, right?

Comment: @PascalT, I'be just edited my answer and added a new fiddle. Check it out. 
Let me know if itsn't clear enough

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I did it the other way, both seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.tooltip {
 position: relative;
}

.tooltiptext {
 position: absolute;
 outline: none;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: #e86d6d;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px rgba(55, 55, 55, .65);
 z-index: 10;
 word-break: break-word;
 padding: 10px;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
 /*-moz-transition: opacity 2s;
 -ms-transition: opacity 2s;
 -o-transition: opacity 2s;*/
 transition-delay: 3s;
 transition: opacity 2s;
  //visibility:hidden;
  
  
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .8s;
 transition: opacity .8s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext:hover {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .8s;
 transition: opacity .8s;
}
```

```html
<body>

<img src="http://www.georgemaps.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/vintage-world-map-high-resolution-old-global-hd-desktop-wallpaper-widescreen-definition-x-1.jpg" 
width="450" height="400" alt="MitarbeiterAnsicht" usemap="#map1">

<map name="map1">

<div class="tooltip">
<area id="meow" shape="rect" coords="20, 195, 150, 220" alt="Schulungssuche" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" >
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Schulungssuche</b><br>Hier können sie nach 
Titel,<br>LMS Code oder Schlagwörtern suchen 
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> Stackoverflow</a>
</span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="13, 310, 287, 300" alt="Colleges" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Colleges</b><br>Colleges sind bestimmte 
Lehrangebote für <br>veschiedene Funktionen und <br>Bereiche
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> Stackoverflow</a>
</span>
</div>

<div class="tooltip">
<area shape="rect" coords="290, 158, 257, 50" alt="Schulungsplan" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
<span class="tooltiptext"><b>Schulungsplan</b><br>Der Schulungsplan 
beinhaltet alle Schulungen,<br>zu denen Sie bereits angemeldet sind, die 
Sie<br>sich selbst zugewiesen haben, die Ihr Vorgesetzter<br>ihnen 
zugewiesen hat oder Compliance Schulungen.<br><font 
color="#FF0000">Compliance Schulungen müssen bearbeitet werden !<br>Sie 
haben ein Fälligkeitsdatum. Überschreiten Sie<br>dieses Fälligkeitsdatum, so 
wird automatisch ihr<br>Vorgesetzer informiert!</font><br><font 
color="0000ff">-> Fragen zu Compliance Schulungen? Box anklicken</font>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> Stackoverflow</a>
</span>
</div>




</map>


</body>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I works fine in Chrome, but sadly not in IE 11.. Is there also a way to make the tooltip positions fixed above the coresponding area ? A clickable link wold be possible if the box stayed for a set amount of time I think.

Comment: @PascalT: I changed my answer. Now when you mouseout from the class `tooltip`, then `tooltiptext` stays for 5 seconds and fades away. You can click the link or `area` in the map also.

Please set the coordinates for `rect` properly. I have just put something.
And please upvote the answer and close the questions.
Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a ton ! :)  Since I am below 15 points, my upvote doesn't show, sorry!

Comment: @PascalT: No issues. Accepting an answer denotes that solution meets the questions expectations. It also stops other people to invest time answering it. Any knowledgeable contributer can edit my answer. Also, Accepting answer will help others by knowing that it's an answer to follow.

Comment: One more thing: it seems it's not working in IE11, I read that it's a problem with `:hover`, can you fix this for me ? (I read this solution here: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287028/imghover-not-working-in-ie) )